# cant assign null value to a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

here once i assign 'img' variable a null value in slideUp, and calling 'click on imageGallery' the img value is 'undefined', why is it like that?

```
$(".imageGallery").click(function(){
    console.log(img+"first");
    var img = $(this).attr("src"); //image source
    console.log(img+"second");
    var num = $(this).attr("alt"); //image name
    $('#popup').slideDown("600",function(){
        $(this).html("<div> <p>"+num+"</p> </div> <img src="+img+">");
        $("#popup p").addClass("popupName");            
        $("#popup img").addClass("popupImg");
        $("#popup div").addClass("popupNameBg");
    })
    $('#popup').click(function(){           
        $('#popup').slideUp("500");
        img = null;
        console.log(img+"third");
        return false;
    })      
})
```

Comment: attaching a click inside of a click....bad bad idea.

Comment: Open your console with F12, type in `null == undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read `img` before you set it. Of course it is going to be undefined since that is how [hoisted variables work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

```
console.log(img+"first");  <--- reading variable before you set the value, it will be undefined
var img = $(this).attr("src"); <-- /set variable value
console.log(img+"second");  <-- will have new value
```

Your code actually is this:

```
var img;
console.log(img+"first");  
img = $(this).attr("src");
console.log(img+"second");
```

Setting it to null means nothing since on every click you are in a new "scope" and define a new variable. So when you do click the pop up it IS setting img to null, problem is you do not use that variable again.

Also on every click you are binding a new click to popup which means you are going to have a lot of click events.

Comment: now i changed variable to global, the img is given null in first log. but what i actually wanted is that, i have a slideDown, in that and display the image from 'img' source to it. and when i click another image, the previous image is being shown until the slideDown completes and then only the new image replaces the old one, what did i do wrong here.?